# Feature extraction for sand dunes and hills using DEM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, feature-extraction

I want to extract only sand dunes, ridges and hills from a DEM.
Note that there are other elevated objects in the DEM as well and on the mountains and ridges that I don’t want.

Is there any way I can automate or semi- automate the process?

Currently I have to mark these features manually, which is very laboursome task.

Hill extraction from image can also work for me if i can make a mask of features I require and later use that mask for feature extraction on DEM.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop+feature-extraction

Answer (score 3):

While I don't have any experience in doing this procedure, I have heard of similar examples. Here are some articles that could help:

- (open access) "Automated accuracy assessment for ridge and valley polylines using high-resolution digital elevation models" https://doi.org/10.1130/GES01477.1
- (open access) "A GIS add-in for automated measurement of sand dune migration using LiDAR-derived multitemporal and high-resolution digital elevation models" https://doi.org/10.1130/GES01329.1

There are also some articles out there for automated detection of drumlins, another form of hill.

- "Automated drumlin shape and volume estimation using high resolution LiDAR imagery (Curvature Based Relief Separation): A test from the Wadena Drumlin Field, Minnesota" https://doi.org/10.1016/j.geomorph.2015.07.020
- "An object-oriented approach to automated landform mapping: A case study of drumlins" https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cageo.2011.04.001

Answer (score 0):

Check out the geomorphon packages in most GIS programs. They will classify ridges, peaks, slopes in your raster. A reclassify will group one or more of these together as desired.